# Math behind throwing a ball into the basket

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile, calculus

I’m assuming we would have to account for gravity and write a function that would create that arc like throw. I have very sparse knowledge about this and I would like to know on how to go about this

Also, how will i figure out the trajectory and angle at which i should throw?

a little irrelevant question , if i were to make machine that could throw the ball in basket , how will i make sure that the throw system throws exactly at a speed.

Comment: You might find [this website](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/3-4-projectile-motion/) to be a useful resource. In general, there are plenty of helpful online resources about "projectile motion".

Answer (score 0):

There is a whole range of choices for initial velocity (speed and direction)  which can put the center of a basketball into the center of a basket.  These can be estimated using the basic kinematics equations in two dimensions:
$x = x_o + (v_{ox})t + (1/2)(a_x)(t^2). and, v_x =  v_{ox} + (a_x)t$. and similar equations for the y direction.  Unfortunately, these equations do not consider the effects of friction with the air. You may want to consider setting up a numeric simulation on a spreadsheet. Also, the ball must come down in a manner that lets it bounce from the backboard or rim into the basket. As for a machine with an adjustable speed, you might start with a compressed spring with an adjustable compression length.